# how to build a long distance wired network

Tags: ethernet, fiber

My shop is 500 meters far from the outer gate, on a steep hill, and there is no straight path or line of sight between the 2 points. How would be the best way to extend the internet connection from the outer gate to the shop router ? I have read this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/156031/very-long-distance-ethernet-connection-for-internet-and-other-data-2000-feet) that solves the problem using ethernet extenders like [this](http://www.trendnet.com/support/supportdetail.asp?prod=265_TPA-311) and another [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/328307/long-distance-networking-options) that recommends using optic fiber and media converters like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009B5AA). I only need the network for common usage (browsing) and the coaxial cable from the ISP is standard RG-6

If I choose the first option (extenders) how exactly would the setup look like ? My guess: the coaxial cable from my ISP would go into the modem and the modem would connect to the first extender placed near the outer gate with RJ45 cable. Then a 500 meters coaxial cable would link this extender to a second one, and a RJ45 cable would link the second extender to my router. Is there a way the modem can be placed at the end point (my shop), and the ISP cable would go directly into the extender ?

If I choose the second option (media converter) I guess I would have to do something similar: to keep the modem next to a media converter, by the outer gate, connected via RJ45 cable and then link the first converter with a 500 meters cable to a second converter to change back from light to electricity ? In this case would the 2 converters be different ?

Which approach is the easiest/best one ? Where can I find more detailed instructions ? Which compatibility issues should I care about ?

Comment: Unfortunately home networking is off-topic here, you may ask on [superuser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: If you have line of sight between the two end points, maybe look at setting up a microwave data link? Then you do not need to dig a 500m trench. You can come by some cheap microwave kit these days, main issue would be nothing blocking the line of sight

Comment: Unfortunately there is no line of sight between the 2 points

Comment: For a business, the ISP will run the cable to the shop, but as your original question is about your residence, then you probably do not have that option. That is one reason home networking is off-topic here. You should ask your original question on the correct SE site. You could try to ask this on [su].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say the setup is much the same either way. One converter to hook up to the ISP kit and one converter to go back to regular Ethernet.

Fiber has a number of advantages.

1. Complete electrical isolation, no need to worry about surge protection.
2. Potential for better performance (though often the ISP will be the bottleneck anyway).
3. The actual cable is generally cheaper (glass is cheap)
4. It's more common/standardised. Ethernet over coax is a niche thing.

And one MAJOR disadvantage.

1. It's not really feasible to diy-terminate/splice fiber. You can buy it pre-terminated but if someone digs through the fiber you are going to need to find someone with field-splicing equipment and experience. Their services may not come cheap.